# Where is this vertical padding in jqGrid coming from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jqgrid

I've noticed a strange bug when using jqGrid with inline editing in chrome. As rows are selected, the vertical padding grows by a pixel or two each time. I'm not sure what's causing this, but I've managed to condense it down to a simplified example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3mrKD/

**UPDATE**: simpler version without jqGrid: http://jsfiddle.net/3mrKD/9/

If you click back and forth between the two rows, you can make each row's height grow indefinitely. Chrome's inspector shows the extra space as padding, but the size doesn't match the metrics inspector value.

I can reproduce this reliably on the latest version of Chrome (26.0.1410.64 m) for both Windows and Mac, but not on any version of Firefox, IE 9 or 10, or Safari.

Does this look like a bug in one of the libraries I'm using? in Chrome?

[image: table cell with extra vertical padding]

HTML:

```
<table id="grid"></table>
```

CSS:

```
td { vertical-align: baseline; }
```

JavaScript:

```
var lastSelected;

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: [{ id: 1, name: "Alice" }, { id: 2, name: "Bob" }],
    colModel: [
        {
            name: 'id'
        },
        {
            name: 'name',
            editable: true
        }
    ],
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
        if (id && id !== lastSelected) {
            $("#grid").jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelected);
            $("#grid").jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
            lastSelected = id;
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is a [bug in chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128306) (and [in webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=107380)). The fix I ended up using (there are others suggested in the linked bugs) was:

```
div.ui-jqgrid td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The earlier declaration of vertical-align I had was from a general CSS reset, so I overrode it where it was a problem.

Comment: I wrote in my answer that I suppose that it's a bug in Google Chrome (in WebKit of cause). What workaround you suggest? I don't found in no reference that the bug is fixed or will be fixed. Do you have some clear confirmation about it?

Comment: I wanted the answer to link to the actual bugs for reference, which is why I added my own. I'll edit to add what I used as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks! I think it would be interesting for other. Please inform me if you would have some progress in official confirmation of the bub or about the fix in Webkit.

Comment: If you're logged into google, you can track the bug and get notified of updates by clicking the star next to the issue number.

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting question. I suppose that it's a bug in Google Chrome: it calculate the height of `<td>` in wrong way. To reduce the problem I suggest to reset `vertical-align` to `middle` at the beginning of row editing. It will include additional `style="vertical-align:middle"` attribute of `<td>`. At the end of editing one can remove the attribute.

One can see the results on [the modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3mrKD/6/). The demo still increase the height of the row to 1px at the beginning of editing, but I think that after playing with other CSS attributes one can eliminate the effect. The code used in the demo is below

```
var lastSelected,
    removeVerticalAlignBaseline = function (rowid) {
        var tr = $(this).jqGrid("getInd", rowid, true),
            $tds = $(tr).find(">td:has(>input)");
        $(tr).find(">td:has(>input)").each(function () {
            this.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
        });
    },
    resetVerticalAlignBaseline = function (rowid) {
        var tr = $(this).jqGrid("getInd", rowid, true),
            $tds = $(tr).find(">td");
        $(tr).find(">td:has(>input)").each(function () {
            this.style.verticalAlign = ""; // remove the style
            // now the style from CSS will be used
        });
    },
    editOptions = {
        keys: true,
        oneditfunc: removeVerticalAlignBaseline,
        aftersavefunc: resetVerticalAlignBaseline,
        afterrestorefunc: resetVerticalAlignBaseline,
    };

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: [{ id: 1, name: "Alice" }, { id: 2, name: "Bob" }],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'id' },
        { name: 'name', editable: true }
    ],
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
        if (id && id !== lastSelected) {
            $(this).jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelected, editOptions);
            $(this).jqGrid('editRow', id, editOptions);
            lastSelected = id;
        }
    },
    height: "auto"
});
```